# cvTranspose Gives a Different Image Size?

Tags: c, opencv

I am new to OpenCV, and I want to transpose a grayscale image but I am getting the wrong output size.

```
// img is an unsigned char image
IplImage *img = cvLoadImage("image.jpg"); // where image is of width=668 height=493
int width  = img->width;
int height = img->height;
```

I want to transpose it:

```
IplImage *imgT = cvCreateImage(cvSize(height,width),img->depth,img->nChannels);

cvTranspose(img,imgT);
```

When I check the images I see that the original image `img` has a size of 329324, which is correct: `493*668* 1` byte as it is an `unsigned char`. However `imgT` has a size of 331328.

I am not really sure where this happened.

EDIT: 1- I am using Windows XP and OpenCV 2.2. 
2- By when i check the image, i meant when i see the values of the variable imgT. Such as the imgT->width, imgT->heigt, imgT->size, etc.

Comment: Which OpenCV version and what platform are you using? (Windows, Linux, MacOSX)

Comment: What do you mean by "when I check the images" ?

Comment: I got my working cvTranspose using converting new image with width = src's height and height = src's width..

Answer (score 11):

This is due to the fact, that OpenCV aligns the rows of the images at 4-byte boundaries. In the first image a row is 668 bytes wide, which is dividable by 4, so your image elements are contiguous.

The second image has a width of 493 (due to the transposing), which is not dividable by 4. The next higher number dividable by 4 is 496, so your rows are actually 496 bytes wide, with 3 unused bytes at the end of each row, to align the rows at 4-byte boundaries. And in fact 496*668 is indeed 331328. So you should always be aware of the fact, that your image elements need not be contiguous (at least they should be contiguous inside a single row).

Answer (score -1):

You can store your image in cv:Mat() and use Mat.t() to transpose it. Rows and columns will be automatically allocated/deallocated so you don't have to worry about the size

Comment: Still (and while I generally agree with the preference for the C++ API) this will present him with the exact same problem of unexpected size *if he dares to inspect it*. He would have to worry about this with *IplImage* either (which is *more or less* managed by OpenCV, too), but he did and found something unexpected, to which you don't really provide an answer. It is more fit as a comment.